# What is the different between "giving an interview" and "having an interview"?

Tags: meaning

I saw someone said this online:

> Have an interview = you are being interviewed
>
> Give an interview = you are interviewing someone

But as I know it, *giving interviews* is being interviewed, agreeing to answer questions, like "give an interview to the reporters".

It's quite confusing how to see the word "interview". Say, at a news conference or in a talkshow, which part is giving an interview, and which part is having an interview?

Comment: Very interesting! This makes me curious too. I usually thought that in a job interview, the interviewer is the one who gives an interview, while the interviewee is the one who has an interview. However, in the context of reporters, a politician would give an interview to them.

Comment: *Have an interview* is ambiguous.  For example, I can say I have an interview at three if I'm going to interview a candidate for a job, or if I'm going to be given an interview myself.

Comment: @snailboat This question makes me think that perhaps both of *have an interview* and *give an interview* can be ambiguous.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Yeah, I think you're right about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with you that both "having" and "giving" an interview can mean that you are the person being interviewed; the difference falls more on the side of whether you are the supplicant or the granter.

That is, if you are applying for a job, you are *having* an interview (and I think most would agree that your potential employer is *giving* it); but if you are a celebrity and you agree to answer questions for a magazine article, you are *giving* the interview.  (I think in this case that hardly anyone would say that the magazine is *having* the interview, though.)

In both cases, the person who is in a position to decide whether the interview happens at all or not is the one who "gives" it.

If you want to be clear about who has what role within the interview itself, I'd suggest that the person answering the questions is "being interviewed" (as we can all agree already, it appears), while the person asking the questions is "conducting the interview".