# to be interviewed or to interview

Tags: phrase-usage, passive-voice

Basically as a greeting for an interview, I want to say something like

> Thank you for the opportunity **to be interviewed** for this scholarship.

However, after doing a little bit of research, I found a user of an English language forum, [WordReference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/offering-me-the-chance-to-be-interviewed.2401183/), asking similar problem.

According to it, the proper greeting is

> Thank you for the opportunity **to interview** (for the programme, for the position, for the scholarship, etc.)

My concern is that I believe instead of using **to interview** which means you are interviewing someone, I should use the phrase **to be interviewed**.

Comment: [Senses 1 and 2](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/interview_2).

Comment: @LordSacha: Originally *to interview* always meant *to **conduct** an interview* (i.e. - to be the "person in charge", the one using the interview to evaluate or present the "interviewee"). But more recently it's also come to be used to mean *to **undergo** an interview* (as the one who's being examined, not as the examiner).

Comment: Note that more often than not, when used in that more modern *undergo an interview* sense, there's also a strong implication of this being an ***achievement***, rather than a simple reference to an activity. So *He interviewed for Oxford* doesn't just tell us what he did - it's usually used in contexts where the speaker wants you to recognize that *he was considered **good enough** to be seriously considered for admission to Oxford* (even if in the event he didn't actually *get* a place, he must have been pretty good to have got as far as an interview).

Comment: I think you can use either one. The first comment by @FumbleFingers explains why pretty well.

Comment: Presumably the interview is just a small part of the process: maybe you should acknowledge that by saying "Thank you for the opportunity to be **considered** for this scholarship".

Comment: related, but probably not a duplicate: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14621/what-is-the-different-between-giving-an-interview-and-having-an-interview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comment, "interview" has a second meaning, in which the roles are reversed.

> verb (used without object) 5. to have an interview; be interviewed (sometimes followed by with): *She interviewed with eight companies before accepting a job.*

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/interview?s=t

I would stay away from the passive voice as much as possible.  Use simple sentence structures -- they are much stronger.

So, something like this:

> Thank you for the opportunity to meet with you.

However, the truth is that the context will make it clear what you are thanking the person for, and you can just say, "Thank you."  Or, you could mention something specific, such as, "Thank you for the tour.  It was fascinating to get a first-hand view of the factory floor."  (Or whatever it was that fascinated you.  Be sincere!

Comment: There's another reason to use a sentence like "Thank you for the opportunity to meet with you" instead of referring to it as an interview.  "Interview" frames the meeting as part of an assembly line process where you're just another candidate, a statistic. Assuming you're one of many qualified applicants, your personal chemistry is often the deciding factor.  You want to use language that focuses on you as a person and the personal interaction that happened during the interview process.  "Meet with you" frames it as a personal interaction and helps the other person recollect it in those terms.

Answer (score 0):

The passive form is definitely much clearer.  It implies that the job seeker is the interviewee, not the person conducting the interview.  Therefore, the job seeker was interviewed by the employment agency.